# How do I serialize an NLP classification PyTorch model

Tags: android, pytorch, fast-ai, torchscript

I am attempting to use a new NLP model within the PyTorch android demo app [Demo App Git](https://github.com/pytorch/android-demo-app/tree/master/PyTorchDemoApp) however I am struggling to serialize the model so that it works with Android.

The demonstration given by PyTorch is as follows for a Resnet model:

```
model = torchvision.models.resnet18(pretrained=True)
model.eval()
example = torch.rand(1, 3, 224, 224)
traced_script_module = torch.jit.trace(model, example)
traced_script_module.save("app/src/main/assets/model.pt")
```

However I am not sure what to use for the 'example' input with my NLP model.

The model that I am using from a fastai tutorial and the python is linked here: [model](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/format/script/github/fastai/course-v3/blob/master/nbs/dl1/lesson3-imdb.ipynb)

Here is the Python used to create my model (using the Fastai library). It is the same as in the model link above, but in a simplified form.

```
from fastai.text import *
path = untar_data('http://files.fast.ai/data/examples/imdb_sample')
path.ls()
#: [PosixPath('/storage/imdb_sample/texts.csv')]
data_lm = TextDataBunch.from_csv(path, 'texts.csv')
data = (TextList.from_csv(path, 'texts.csv', cols='text')
                .split_from_df(col=2)
                .label_from_df(cols=0)
                .databunch())
bs=48
path = untar_data('https://s3.amazonaws.com/fast-ai-nlp/imdb')
data_lm = (TextList.from_folder(path)
            .filter_by_folder(include=['train', 'test', 'unsup']) 
            .split_by_rand_pct(0.1)
            .label_for_lm()           
            .databunch(bs=bs))
learn = language_model_learner(data_lm, AWD_LSTM, drop_mult=0.3)
learn.fit_one_cycle(1, 1e-2, moms=(0.8,0.7))
learn.unfreeze()
learn.fit_one_cycle(10, 1e-3, moms=(0.8,0.7))
learn.save_encoder('fine_tuned_enc')
path = untar_data('https://s3.amazonaws.com/fast-ai-nlp/imdb')
data_clas = (TextList.from_folder(path, vocab=data_lm.vocab)
             .split_by_folder(valid='test')
             .label_from_folder(classes=['neg', 'pos'])
             .databunch(bs=bs))
learn = text_classifier_learner(data_clas, AWD_LSTM, drop_mult=0.5)
learn.load_encoder('fine_tuned_enc')
learn.fit_one_cycle(1, 2e-2, moms=(0.8,0.7))
learn.freeze_to(-2)
learn.fit_one_cycle(1, slice(1e-2/(2.6**4),1e-2), moms=(0.8,0.7))
learn.freeze_to(-3)
learn.fit_one_cycle(1, slice(5e-3/(2.6**4),5e-3), moms=(0.8,0.7))
learn.unfreeze()
learn.fit_one_cycle(2, slice(1e-3/(2.6**4),1e-3), moms=(0.8,0.7))
```

Comment: genreally what input you pass to your model ? and what's the shape of it ?

Comment: a string of text. E.g. learn.predict("I really loved that movie, it was awesome!")

Comment: when you trained the model, i m very sure u didn't pass the string like this. how was the shape of the input u passed when u trained the model ?

Comment: That is one of the things I am unsure about, how to work out the shape of the input used to train the model. All the code I used to create the model is linked above in the second link. I'll see if I can shorten the relevant code into a comment

Comment: I have added the training of the model above.

Comment: for fast.ai models there is specific way of exporting/serializing using Learner.export function. can you explore on that ?

Comment: Looking through the docs now and can't see anything promising... I'll keep looking there though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked out how to do this after a while. The issue was that the Fastai model wasn't tracing correctly no matter what shape of input I was using.

In the end, I used another text classification model and got it to work. I wrote a tutorial about how I did it, in case it can help anyone else.

[NLP PyTorch Tracing Tutorial](https://medium.com/@mix29050/running-nlp-models-on-pytorch-android-api-588c6a038154)

Begin by opening a new Jupyter Python Notebook using your preferred cloud machine provider (I use Paperspace).

Next, copy and run the code in the PyTorch Text Classification tutorial. But replace the line…

```
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
```

With…

```
device = torch.device("cpu")
```

NOTE: It caused issues tracing when the device was set to CUDA so I forced it on to the CPU. (this will slow training, but inference on the mobile will run at the same speed as it is cpu anyway)

Lastly, run the code below to correctly trace the model to allow it to be run on Android:

```
data = DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=1, collate_fn=generate_batch)
for text, offsets, cls in data:
        text, offsets, cls = text.to(device), offsets.to(device), cls.to(device)
example = text, offsets
traced_script_module = torch.jit.trace(model, example)
traced_script_module.save("model.pt")
```

In addition, if you would like a CSV copy of the vocab list for use on Android when you are making predictions, run the following code afterwards:

```
import pandas as pd
vocab = train_dataset.get_vocab()
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(vocab.stoi, orient='index', columns=['token'])
df[:30]
df.to_csv('out.csv')
```

This model should work fine on Android using the PyTorch API.

Comment: Import your tutorial here as answer or your answer will be deleted by moderators in few days. this is considered link-only answer